# How do I design a relative layout that maintains the ratios in all size of screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How do i design a relative layout in xml that maintains the ratios in all size of screen? wrap content and match parent is not providing the best output. layout is not maintaining the sequence in different screen size. The code is given bellow, i can't put any images as I just opened an account.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0000ff" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00ff00" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00ff00" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0000ff" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp" 
    android:background="#000000" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:text="@string/ftfl" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/aa"
        android:src="@drawable/aa" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ab"
        android:src="@drawable/ac" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ac"
        android:src="@drawable/ad" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ad"
        android:src="@drawable/ae" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ae"
        android:src="@drawable/ab" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you just show layout design image?

Comment: http://www.it-docs.net/ddata/901.pdf have a look

Answer (score 0):

To make the `layout_weight` perform better, use respective height or width value as `0dp`.
Your code can be like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff0000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0000ff" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00ff00" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00ff00" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff0000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0000ff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:background="#000000" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:text="@string/ftfl" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/aa"
            android:src="@drawable/aa" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ab"
            android:src="@drawable/ac" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ac"
            android:src="@drawable/ad" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ad"
            android:src="@drawable/ae" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ae"
            android:src="@drawable/ab" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTE:** For Relative layout in the bottom, you should provide a `layout_weight` value based on the design requirement and also modify the `weightsum` value of parent `LinearLayout`, Then you are done!

Comment: I've tried changing weightsum but it was not useful. And relative layout don't support weight. it'll be helpful if u explain how 0dp works here. Thank you.

Comment: Inside Relative Layout `layout_weight` won't work, But since `RelativeLayout` inside a linear layout you can give layout_weight for whole `RelativeLayout`. Can you tell me if you want to maintain the ratio for RelativeLayout or content inside the Relative Layout?